I am using kafka want to know ideal value of configurations
heartbeat interval ms
session timeout ms
max poll interval ms
My use case is I am polling in a interval of 3 mins from multiple topics, want to know what should be the ideal configuration value of above configs.
heartbeat interval ms is 96000
session timeout ms is 500000
max poll interval ms is 480000
** with these configuration kafka is doing rebalancing for around 20 mins and due to this no messages were fetched from it even messages are there in topic.**
